# Sublime: PHP embedded on HTML do not apply style correcly

Tags: sublimetext3

I need make some changes on `HTML.tmLanguage`, but I know now exactly how I'll do that. My problem is that my embedded PHP code are showing incorrectly and variably.

[image]

Note that if I embbed a PHP code inside a HTML attribute, it doesn't works property, or even if I use as JS string value.

I just need some tutorial or documentation to make it works. It's very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

If my memory serves me well, the [HTML5](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML5) is far better at handling PHP and JavaScript inside HTML